# ¿Por qué me sale un espacio entre el primer texto y el número?

Tags: python, jupyter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No entiendo por qué sale el espacio entre la primera palabra (texto prueba) y el número 6.

Answer (score 5):

La función `print(x)` imprime `x` y luego avanza una línea.

Cómo estás imprimiendo un texto que ya tiene un avance de línea (`\n`), da un total de dos avances, dejando una línea en blanco.

Puedes eliminar el `\n` en la cadena o bien imprimir sin avance de línea, agregando la opción `end=''`:

```
print(x, end="")
```

Esta opción te permite indicar que deseas imprimir luego de imprimir todos los demás argumentos, y se usa normalmente para suprimir el avance de línea.

Answer (score 2):

La function `print` siempre (es decir, por defecto) emite un salto de lineas cuando termina.

Por eso tu programa va a produce la siguiente:

Primer `print`:

```
"texto prueba \n"
"\n"
```

Segundo `print`:

```
6
```

Tercero print:

```
"texto prueba \n"
"texto prueba \n"
"texto prueba \n"
"texto prueba \n"
"texto prueba \n"
"texto prueba \n"
"texto prueba \n"
"texto prueba \n"
"texto prueba \n"
"texto prueba \n"
"\n"
```

Si no quieres la ultima "\n" puedes pasar el parametro `end`.

```
print(text3, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Eso ocurre porque le estas metiendo un salto de linea (`\n`) al final del `text3`. Si se lo quitas, te debería quedar:

```
text3 = text1 + " " + text2
```

Y ya no habría un salto de línea de más.